# Explain how `eigen` helps inverting a matrix

Tags: r, eigenvalues, matrix-decomposition, matrix-inverse, cholesky-decomposition

My question relates to a computation technique exploited in `geoR:::.negloglik.GRF` or `geoR:::solve.geoR`.

In a linear mixed model setup:
$$
Y=X\beta+Zb+e
$$
where $\beta$ and $b$ are the fixed and random effects respectively. Also, $\Sigma=\text{cov}(Y)$

When estimating the effects, there is a need to compute 
$$ 
(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}X'\Sigma^{-1} Y
$$
which can normally be done using something like `solve(XtS_invX,XtS_invY)`, but sometimes $(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)$ is almost non-invertible, so `geoR` employ the trick

```
t.ei=eigen(XtS_invX)
crossprod(t(t.ei$vec)/sqrt(t.ei$val))%*%XtS_invY
```

(can be seen in `geoR:::.negloglik.GRF` and `geoR:::.solve.geoR`)
which amounts to decomposing
$$
(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)=\Lambda D \Lambda^{-1}\\
$$
where $\Lambda'=\Lambda^{-1}$ and therefore
$$
(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)^{-1}=(D^{-1/2}\Lambda^{-1})'(D^{-1/2}\Lambda^{-1})
$$

Two questions:

1. How does this eigen decomposition helps inverting $(X'\Sigma^{-1}X)$?
2. Is there any other viable alternatives (that is robust and stable)? (e.g. `qr.solve` or `chol2inv`?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1) The eigendecomposition doesn't really help that much.  It is certainly more numerically stable than a Cholesky factorization, which is helpful if your matrix is ill-conditioned/nearly singular/has a high condition number.  So you can use the eigendecomposition and it will give you **A** solution to your problem.  But there's little guarantee that it will be the **RIGHT** solution.  Honestly, once you explicitly invert $\Sigma$, the damage is already done.  Forming $X^T \Sigma^{-1} X$ just makes matters worse.  The eigendecomposition will help you win the battle, but the war is most certainly lost.

2) Without knowing the specifics of your problem, this is what I would do.  First, perform a Cholesky factorization on $\Sigma$ so that $\Sigma = L L^T$.  Then perform a QR factorization on $L^{-1} X$ so that $L^{-1} X = QR$.  Please be sure to compute $L^{-1} X$ using forward substitution - **DO NOT** explicitly invert $L$.  So then you get:
$$
\begin{array}{}
X^T \Sigma^{-1} X & = & X^T (L L^T)^{-1} X \\
& = & X^T L^{-T} L^{-1} X \\
& = & (L^{-1} X)^T (L^{-1} X) \\
& = & (Q R)^T Q R \\
& = & R^T Q^T Q T \\
& = & R^T R
\end{array}
$$
From here, you can solve any right hand side you want.  But again, please do not explicitly invert $R$ (or $R^T R$).  Use forward and backward substitutions as necessary.

BTW, I'm curious about the right hand side of your equation.  You wrote that it's $X^T \Sigma Y$.  Are you sure it's not $X^T \Sigma^{-1} Y$?  Because if it were, you could use a similar trick on the right hand side:
$$
\begin{array}{}
X^T \Sigma^{-1} Y & = & X^T (L L^T)^{-1} Y \\
& = & X^T L^{-T} L^{-1} Y \\
& = & (L^{-1} X)^T L^{-1} Y \\
& = & (Q R)^T L^{-1} Y \\
& = & R^T Q^T L^{-1} Y
\end{array}
$$
And then you can deliver the coup de grâce when you go to solve for $\beta$:
$$
\begin{array}{}
X^T \Sigma^{-1} X \beta & = & X^T \Sigma^{-1} Y \\
R^T R \beta & = & R^T Q^T L^{-1} Y \\
R \beta & = & Q^T L^{-1} Y \\
\beta & = & R^{-1} Q^T L^{-1} Y
\end{array}
$$
Of course, you would never explicitly invert $R$ for the final step, right?  That's just a backward substitution.  :-)

Comment: Thanks. this is a helpful response. Just to be explicit, is your chol/qr alternative going to help win the war? or just winning the game better than what eigen does?

Comment: That's a tough question to answer. I am confident that combining the Cholesky and QR factorizations will give you a **better** answer (and a faster answer). Whether it's the **right** answer really depends on the source of the problem. In this case, there are 2 potential sources.  Either the columns of $X$ are nearly linearly dependent or $\Sigma$ is approaching singular.  When you form $X^T \Sigma^{-1} X$, these problems amplify each other.  The Cholesky+QR approach does not (and can not) mitigate either of these problems, but it does prevent the situation from getting worse.